# LinkedList retains values even after returning from recursion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have this function to find all the paths from root to leaf in a BST.

```
public static void paths(Node node, LinkedList<Integer> list) {

    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    list.add(node.data);

    if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
        print(list);
        return;
    } else {
        paths(node.left, list);
        paths(node.right, list);
    }
}

public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> list1) {
    System.out.println("Contents of list: " + list1);
}
```

I call it using:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
paths(bt.root, list);
```

e.g:

```
07
02
01 05
```

It prints:

```
7 2 1
7 2 1 5 [instead of 7 2 5]
```

Somehow the value 1 is retained in the "list" even after it returns from the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, there's only a single `LinkedList` object in use here. xyz incorrectly described this as using pass by reference, but it's actually passing the value of `list` which *is* a reference, by value. (Changes to the parameter itself, such as assigning it a different value, aren't visible to the caller; changes within the object that the parameter *refers to* are visible.)

It's *really* important that you understand how variables, objects and references work in Java. When you write (say):

```
Node node = new Node();
```

... then the value of `node` is not a `Node` object. It's a *reference* to a `Node` object. Assignment and parameter passing deal with that value (the reference) not the object. So for example:

```
Node node1 = new Node();
Node node2 = node1;
```

`node1` and `node2` now refer to the same object - there's no object copying involved.

As for how you can fix this, there are two options that spring to mind:

- Create a *copy* of the linked list on each recursive step, so that changes are independent
- "Pop" the newly added value off the end of the linked list at the end of the method, so that when a method of recursion depth `n` completes, the linked list is back to having `n-1` elements.

You can do this by simply adding a call to:

```
list.removeLast();
```

either in both branches, or in a finally block, or removing the explicit `return`:

```
if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
    print(list);
    // Note no return statement
} else {
    paths(node.left, list);
    paths(node.right, list);
}
list.removeLast();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It really helped me clear my concept of pass by value for Java!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you removing anything from the list. So it stays there once added.

Comment: I call "paths(node.left, list)" recursively. So when it returns I expect it to have only 7 and 2. Why is it still containing 1?

Comment: list is passed by refference so any change in one recursive branch is seen everywhere

Comment: Seriously? Why is list passed by reference? Because when I used array instead of list, it works fine. So array is passed by value! But then what is passed by reference and what is passed by value? How do I remember.

Comment: all primtives are passed by value which means that, in a function call, there's a local copy that you can modify without changing the original variable. All non-primitive are passed by reference.

Comment: @xyz: No they're not. The reference is passed by value, which is a different thing. It's worth being clear about this, otherwise you'll confuse people who really understand what pass-by-reference entails.

Answer (score 1):

The list is created outside the scope of the recursive function which means that it's the same list that's being used in all recursive calls. You are recursively adding elements to the list so even though the values would be `7 2 5` in one recursive sequence, `1` would have been added to the same list in another recursive sequence.

Comment: So the call  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();  paths(bt.root, list);  is incorrect!  can you suggest the change necessary?